# Fastest way to get metadata from a website

Tags: php, html, preg-match, metadata

I'm trying to get 'title' from websites, at the moment I'm using `preg_match` to get the title but it's very slow to load.

What I have at the moment:

This passes links through to a function:

```
<?php 
foreach($savedLinks as $s)
{
    echo "<div class='savedLink'>";
        echo "<h5>" . getMetaData($s) . "</h5>";
        echo "<a href='" . $s . "'>" . $s . "</a><br />";
    echo "</div>";
}
?>
```

This function grabs the title from each website passed in:

```
function getMetaData($url)
{
    if(!@file_get_contents($url))
    {
        return "";
    }
    else
    {
        if(preg_match('/<title>(.+)<\/title>/',file_get_contents($url),$matches) && isset($matches[1]))
            return $matches[1];
        else
            return "Not Found";  
    }
}
```

Is there a fast way to get 'title' from each page?

Comment: one word [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)

Comment: I've tried DOM but when trying to get the 'title' from around 10 pages it starts to load very slow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that the file_get_contents is taking a lot longer than the preg_match, which I would expect to be pretty fast.

If you're doing this across a lot of sites, this method may not work, but you might want to look into byte range requests.  If you can predict that the  tag is within the first X bytes of the HTML response, you can do a partial request with byte-range and avoid having to move the whole document over the wire just to get the title tag.  If the pages are dynamically generated it would require that the code on the server support this.  If they're static docs, chances are good that byte range requests are supported.

https://serverfault.com/questions/398219/how-can-i-enable-byte-range-request

As this example suggests in the second answer, also try enabling keepalive by changing "Connection: close" to "Connection: keep-alive".  Again, this will only work if you're hitting the same server multiple times and if the server has it enabled.  Those two things together could save a lot of time per request.

Comment: I'm not quite sure as to how to get a websites 'title' using this method?

Comment: Can you post a URL that you will be scraping for title so I can see if it supports byte-range requests properly and post some working code?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't look like YouTube supports byte-range requests for its HTML pages.  I sent a Range header and got back a 200 response rather than the expected 206 "Partial".  If your target is YouTube, you'll just have to get a faster connection to work from.  Try using curl so you can request Connection: keepalive which should make subsequent requests a little faster (perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

You need a DOM parser for retrieving an HTML page information quickly. I have used the following DOM parser for the example:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

**Download:**

http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

**for example:**

```
<?php

   include('simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php');

   // Create DOM from URL or file
   $html = file_get_html('http://joinform.com.au');


   foreach($html->find('title') as $e)
      echo $e->innertext . '<br>';


?>
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your method and it still takes about 10> seconds to load the page when getting 10+ different websites 'title'.

Comment: You can not omit connection time with other website. Only possible if you have very high speed internet connection.